# How can I prevent duplicate fragments?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I've been wracking my head for days now trying to figure out how to better handle a fragment interaction so that the event only triggers once. Essentially I have a main activity that holds a single main fragment container. That main container houses three other container fragments (the columns). Each of these three fragments then house various other child fragments as shown below.

[image: Default layout]

When I click one of the child fragments, the main activity gets the fragment manager and replaces the single main fragment container with the fragment clicked; essentially it's taking the fragment and making it fullscreen.

[image: Child Fragment clicked fullscreen]

The problem that I'm having is that after the child fragment is fullscreen, any additional clicks within the fragment creates subsequent fragments. Thus if I click the fullscreen fragment 4 times I end up with 5 fragment views; the initial click from the main activity & 4 duplicates.

**TL/DR - Question:How do I prevent the fragment from replacing itself after it becomes fullscreen?**

MFDTailboard.java

```
public class MFDTailboard extends Activity implements Calendar.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
    ....
    public void onCalendarFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.MFDTailboardContainer, Calendar.newInstance("Calendar Fragment", "CalFrag"))
            .addToBackStack("Fullscreen Calendar")
            .commit();
    }
```

Calendar.java

```
public class Calendar extends Fragment implements TextView.OnClickListener {
....
        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false);

        nextScheduledDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.NextScheduledDate);
        nextScheduledDate.setOnClickListener(this);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onCalendarFragmentInteraction(null);
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
            // TODO: Update argument type and name
            public void onCalendarFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
```

Layout activity_mfdtailboard.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/MFDTailboardContainer"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout fragment_calendar_callback_container (first of 3 columns)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/FragmentContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2"
tools:context=".fragments.CalendarCallback">

</LinearLayout>
```

Layout fragment_calendar.xml (fullscreen / child fragment)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/calendar_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/calendar_header"
            android:id="@+id/calendar_header"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/NextScheduledLabel"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/next_scheduled_label"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/RemainingLabel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:text="@string/remaining_label"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/RemainingCount"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/remaining_count"
                            android:textSize="30sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/NextScheduledDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/next_scheduled_day"
                    android:textSize="102sp" />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/NextScheduledMonth"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/next_scheduled_month"
                    android:textSize="36sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
            android:id="@+id/HorizontalLine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/CycleFirstDate"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/cycle_first_date"
                            android:textSize="30dp" />

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/CycleFirstDay"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/cycle_first_day"
                            android:textSize="18dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/CycleSecondDate"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/cycle_second_date"
                            android:textSize="30dp" />

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/CycleSecondDay"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/cycle_second_day"
                            android:textSize="18dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/CycleThirdDate"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/cycle_third_date"
                            android:textSize="30dp" />

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/CycleThirdDay"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/cycle_third_day"
                            android:textSize="18dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could keep your fragments instances inside an array, like this:

```
Fragment[] myFragments = {
    new Fragment1(),
    new Fragment2(),
    ...
};
```

Then you could swap them by calling `changeFragment(myFragments[i])`

```
public void changeFragment(Fragment fragment){
    if(null != fragment && fragment != actualFragment){
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Hope it works.

Best regards.

Comment: The child fragment is never null, just put in a smaller container based upon the layout. The fragment transaction gets run every time. As the onFragmentInteraction is bound to the main activity, it would still be running the fragment creation code every time you clicked on the fragment, just through an array as opposed to separate methods as I have now. Can you explain how you see putting my fragments into an array would limit their creation to a single catch of onFragmentInteraction?

Comment: Having an array of instances may simplify not attempting to overwrite the actual fragment being displayed with another instance of the same fragment. Also I recommend you check where you are instantiating your fragments, '.replace(R.id.MFDTailboardContainer, Calendar.newInstance("Calendar Fragment", "CalFrag"))' this line seems to be the one creating all those extra instances when you click on Calendar. Hope this is of any help to you.